# Stata foreach loop says tabulate is not a valid command name?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, stata, stata-macros, tabulate

Using Stata v18. I just want to tab all variables in the local varlist (in my original data, it's to display "missed" ER variables, but otherwise no difference). Any ideas on why Stata keeps telling me that

```
tab `var'
```

is not a valid command name?

I just want to `tab` all variables in the local varlist (percent frequencies for each variable in the list). Ultimately, I'm doing a larger loop splitting out the varlist by state, by caseworker, etc., but this is the KISS version.

I've replicated and traced my problem using example dataset nlsw88.dta:

```
clear
sysuse nlsw88.dta

set trace on
local varlist "married never_married grade collgrad south smsa c_city industry occupation union"
foreach var in `varlist' {
        tab `var'
        display "`var'"
    } 
set trace off
```

Stata repeatedly generates the following output and error message:

```
. clear

. sysuse nlsw88.dta
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

. 
. set trace on

. local varlist "married never_married grade collgrad south smsa c_city indu
> stry occupation union"

. foreach var in `varlist' {
  2.         tab `var'
  3.                 display "`var'"
  4.         } 
- foreach var in `varlist' {
= foreach var in married never_married grade collgrad south smsa c_city indu
> stry occupation union {
-      tab `var'
=      tab married
     is not a valid command name
  display "`var'"
  }
r(199);

end of do-file

r(199);
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good in principle.

I think Stata is objecting to an unusual character that has crept in to your code, or more than one.

Notice that the error message you show us is NOT that `tabulate` (or `tab`) is not a valid command name. It is that

```
   is not a valid command name
```

Look for unusual characters before `tabulate`. Or just delete all the characters before `tabulate` and try again.

Preparing code in MS Word is sometimes behind this problem. It is a word processor, not a text editor.

All that said,

```
sysuse nlsw88.dta, clear 

tab1 married never_married grade collgrad south smsa c_city industry occupation union
```

is a simple alternative to your loop.

If you're checking for missing values in your real data, see

```
help misstable
```

or the `missings` command from the *Stata Journal*, for which

```
search dm0085, entry
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that worked - there's just empty space in front of tabulate, which is automatic when you use foreach, but ok?? Thank you!

Comment: That cannot be so. Even "empty space" is some space characters, which themselves will not bite, but other characters might be. Indentation when using `foreach` depends on what, if anything, your text editor does.